# Override JdbcTemplate method in Groovy unit tests

Tags: grails, groovy, jdbctemplate

Disclaimer: I know, the integration test is in progress, I just need to test what happens after the  jdbc query ;)

Hi,
writing some unit test for a grails service class, I have a small problem regarding a method that contains a call to jdbcTemplate.query(string sql, Object[] params, RowMapper rm)

In order to test what happens after the query, I need to provide a dummy value. In a previous test, I was able to override a queryForList using :

```
Service service = new Service()
def jdbcTemplate = [queryForList : {q, o -> return [1,2,3]}] as JdbcTemplate
service.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
```

without any issue. However, for the query method, no sucess . With

```
def jdbcTemplate = [query : {q, o, rm -> 'dummy'}] as JdbcTemplate
def jdbcTemplate = [query : {String q, Object[] o, RowMapper rm -> 'dummy'}] as JdbcTemplate
def jdbcTemplate = [query : {String q, Object o, RowMapper rm -> 'dummy'}] as JdbcTemplate
```

all fail with a

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: 
JdbcTemplate_groovyProxy.query() is applicable for argument types: 
(java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList, com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6) 
values: [select something from something where id = ? , [1], Service$_method_closure1@16aca316]
Possible solutions: query(java.lang.String, org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor), 
query(java.lang.String, [Ljava.lang.Object;, org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor), 
query(java.lang.String, org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementSetter, 
org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor), query(java.lang.String,
org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor, [Ljava.lang.Object;), 
query(java.lang.String, org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper), 
query(java.lang.String, [Ljava.lang.Object;, 
org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper)
```

Any hint ? Or am I doing something really bad here ? (I'm new to groovy)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I manage to make it work (I forgot, I'm stuck with grails 1.3.7 on that project, it will be "upgraded later if we have time" )

So, using mockFor :

```
def jdbcTemplate = mockFor(JdbcTemplate.class)
jdbcTemplate.demand.query() {q, o, rm -> ['dummy']}
service.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate.createMock());
```

and that works. As you notice, unlike my example in the question, I return ['dummy'] as a list, no 'dummy' as a String. I thought that was the mistake but nope, changes nothing :/

Comment: hmm, funny thing here: moving on to the next method, I need to mock again the queryForList. so I use :  jdbcTemplate.demand.queryForList() {q, o -> [] } which does not work. Only  map coercion here, as in the question, works. Anyone knows why ?

Answer (score 1):

Even though this should be possible with map coercion, as you're attempting, I would suggest using the [Spock Framework](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/spock_primer.html) for this.

The `Specification` class, which you override to write a test, contains the `Mock` and `Stub` methods so you can do stuff like this:

```
def mockJdbc = Mock( JdbcTemplate ) {
    query(_, _, _) >> 'DUMMY'
}
```

This should even give you proper error messages so you can figure out what's wrong more easily.

Comment: thanks for the pointer, I will look into that. I manage to make my test work using mockFor(see below) but still has no idea why map coercion (thanks for the name) did not work :/